# How to create a circle with the Array Modifier

Tags: modifiers

I was trying to create the same as in this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whjFb0xFoLk

But when I do exact the same my objects keep regrowing. So each next object will be even bigger then the one before.

Can someone please tell me what I did wrong here?

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. The user ask for a specific properites that make bigger the objects. If you refer to the title it's a duplicate but the question itself is different!

Answer (score 2):

You have probably scaled your empty (the empty is the object that you use as offset object in the tutorial).

For correcting your error you can select your empty and then press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> for reseting the scale of your object.